# How to print linux group names on multiple line instead of single line output

Tags: linux, unix, sed, yaml

I have tried getent, group command, id -Gn $user and some sed combination but I don't think I am able to achieve hence reaching out to fellow programmers.
I want to be able to print this : groups abc123
Output 
abc123 : devops build test design

Expected Output
groups:
  - devops
  - build
  - test
  - design

Comment: You can start from there:  groups abc123 | sed 's/ /\n - /g'
And then try to improve

Comment: If your shell is bash (or supports arrays), you can do something simple like `arr=($(groups)); printf "%s\n" ${arr[@]}`. If you want the leading `'- '`, then you can do `arr=($(groups)); printf -- "- %s\n" ${arr[@]}`

Comment: thank you @Sergius that partly worked but atleast got my sed right :)

Comment: thank you @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, you are trying to convert the groups of your user to an `yaml` array, try to use:

```
echo "groups:" ; for i in $(id -Gn myuser);do echo "  - $i" ;done

groups:
  - users
  - lp
  - vboxusers
  - kvm
```

You can use too:

```
echo "groups: [ $(groups myuser | sed -e 's/.\+\s\+:\s\+\(.\+\)/\1/g' -e 's/\(\s\+\)/, /g') ]"

groups: [ myuser, lp, vboxusers, kvm ]
```

Comment: yes correct :) thanks for this gonna try all suggestions one by one to see which works best for my piece of script

Comment: This only works when there are no spaces in the group names.

Answer (score 9):

In response to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766078/how-to-print-linux-group-names-on-multiple-line-instead-of-single-line-output/50381984#comment73288972_34766151) by @Chris that

> This only works for groups without spaces in the names!

I should mention that the accepted solution by @c4f4t0r and the solution by @bibi will work in most cases. I am running Cygwin, and the `Windows` part of the equation is probably why I hit this problem more often. Still, a group could be made with non-standard characters in normal Linux (I think), so I'll give the solution for group names with spaces. Spaces always make life fun!

I'll quickly give an example where spaces cause a problem. To see the group names with spaces, we look at the entire output of `id`

```
$ id
uid=1(me) gid=545(Users) 
groups=545(Users),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),11(Authenticated Users),
4095(CurrentSession),66048(LOCAL)
```

(Note: I did make the output a little more pleasing to the eye here on StackOverflow.)

From this, we see that the groups are `{'Users', 'CONSOLE LOGON', 'Authenticated Users', 'CurrentSession', 'LOCAL'}`

We can see the problem with the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34766356/6505499) in this case.

```
$ echo "groups:" ; for i in $(id -Gn);do echo "  - $i" ;done
    groups:
      - Users
      - CONSOLE
      - LOGON
      - Authenticated
      - Users
      - CurrentSession
      - LOCAL
```

A couple of groups get their names split up. To get the output we want, we need to use the id command, which takes a `--zero` ( `-z` ) flag. For more details on all the flags passed to `id`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375838/6505499).

```
$ man id | grep -A 1 "\-\-zero"
       -z, --zero
              delimit entries with NUL characters, not whitespace;
```

Our approach will need to be a bit different to those given above, but follow a lot of the same principles:

```
$ echo "groups:"; printf "%s" "  - "; id -Gnz | \
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\0"; OFS="\n  - "}{NF--; print}'
groups:
  - Users
  - CONSOLE LOGON
  - Authenticated Users
  - CurrentSession
  - LOCAL
```

The reason that we have a slightly-more-complicated `awk` is that there is always a trailing `NUL`, which we do not want in this case. The `\` allows me to continue onto the next line with the same command, making things easier to read. The command is equivalent to:

```
$ echo "groups:"; printf "%s" "  - "; id -Gnz | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\0"; OFS="\n  - "}{NF--; print}'
```

Comment: `id` on macos has no `-z` flag

Comment: Which flags can you see on a MacOS? Try `man id` to find out.

Comment: I'm not on MacOS but I also get the no -z flag:
 -a     ignore, for compatibility with other versions
 -Z, --context
        print only the security context of the current user
 -g, --group
        print only the effective group ID
 -G, --groups
        print all group IDs
 -n, --name
        print a name instead of a number, for -ugG
 -r, --real
        print the real ID instead of the effective ID, with -ugG
 -u, --user
        print only the effective user ID
 --help display this help and exit
 --version
        output version information and exit

Comment: Thanks for the info, @bibi and @Tim_Edwards . It seems that the thing to do when there's no separate-on-null flag might be to parse the output of `id`, isolating the `groups=` line, and then matching on something like `[0-9]+[(]` **(** `[^)(]+` **)** `[)]` where the grouping parentheses are in a non-code font for emphasis. (Extended REGEX)

Comment: Here is a **non-fully-tested** and **definitely-not-robust** first stab at code for the no-separate-on-null case, specifically for @bibi and @Tim_Edwards : `echo "groups:"; id | sed 's#^.*groups.\(.*\)$#\1#g' | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's#^[0-9]\+[(]\([^)(]\+\)[)]#  - \1#g'` (Here we have Normal REGEX in the `sed`)

Answer (score 3):

using `bash`:

```
for i in `groups`; do echo $i; done
```

using `tr`:

```
groups | tr \  \\n
```

Comment: thank you @bibi I got to learn something new. I had never tried tr command before. This works as well - but we get output without the hyphen in front of group names but I played around with tr a bit and figured out.

Comment: This only works for groups without spaces in the names!

Answer (score 3):

How about this for a succinct solution that deals with spaces:

```
id -Gnz | tr "\0" "\n"
```