# comma separated list from $FT_USER

Tags: unix

I need an Unix command which will display a list of my groups separated with commas. So, `groups $FT_USER` is only displaying the list, but I need to separate it into a comma-separated list!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to replace every character from one set with those of another, use `tr` (*tr*ansliterate).

In this case, we want to replace all spaces with commas:

```
$ groups $FT_USER | tr ' ' ','
```

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this (meaning the great answers by [@Kusalananda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38206889/6505499) and [@SriniV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207569/6505499), which will work in the majority of cases) will not work for Cygwin. Actually, it won't work whenever there are groups with spaces in the names. I think this usually only happens on Windows (Cygwin), but it leads to incorrect results. I'll quickly give an example where it causes a problem.

```
$ groups $FT_USER
Users CONSOLE LOGON Authenticated Users CurrentSession LOCAL
```

The groups here are `{'Users', 'CONSOLE LOGON', 'Authenticated Users', 'CurrentSession', 'LOCAL'}`. Trust me on this one, or go see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50381984/6505499), where there are some more details.

The command given before by @Kusalananda, which will work in *most* cases, gives the following, incorrect output.

```
$ groups $FT_USER | tr ' ' ','
Users,CONSOLE,LOGON,Authenticated,Users,CurrentSession,LOCAL
```

The command from @SriniV will give the same output. Some of the group names are "split". We get `...,CONSOLE,LOGIN,...` instead of `...,CONSOLE LOGIN,...` and `...,Authenticated,Users,...` instead of `...,Authenticated Users,...`

(I know, I know: "Why are you using Cygwin?" Answer: The job requires it.)

To get the output we want, we need to use the [`id`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html) command, which takes a `--zero` flag:

```
$ man id | grep -A 1 "\-\-zero"
       -z, --zero
              delimit entries with NUL characters, not whitespace;
```

We can then use `tr` or `awk` as described by @Kusalananda and
@SriniV, respectively. One problem is that there will always be a trailing `,` because of the trailing `NUL`. This can be rectified by a `sed` command where we print everything but the last comma, `sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/'`. Note that the `.*` will print everything until the last comma. The `\1` prints everything in the (backslash escaped) parentheses, i.e. `\1` will print whatever was found by the `.*` part of `\(.*\),`

Let's show this complete answer with `tr`

```
$ id --zero -Gn $FT_USER | tr '\0' ',' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/'
Users,CONSOLE LOGON,Authenticated Users,CurrentSession,LOCAL
```

Now, we'll do it with `awk`

```
$ id --zero -Gn $FT_USER | gawk -F "\0" '{$1=$1}1' OFS="," | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/'
Users,CONSOLE LOGON,Authenticated Users,CurrentSession,LOCAL
```

---

#### Edit

If you feel (as I do) that the `sed` at the end is a bit of a cheat, here's an alternative:

```
$ id -Gnz $FT_USER | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\0"; OFS=","}{NF--; print}'                          
Users,CONSOLE LOGON,Authenticated Users,CurrentSession,LOCAL
```

Also note that, wherever you see `--zero -Gn` above, you can replace it with `-Gnz`. `-G` prints out all of the groups to which the current user belongs, `-n` prints the name, rather than the group id (GID), and `-z` does what we described `--zero` doing above

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `awk`

```
groups | gawk -F " " '{$1=$1}1' OFS=","
```

use the output of the groups command and read it through awk program with `-F " "` specifying it as a space separated value. Then the `$1=$1` is always true and we simply print the output with a new output field separator ' using `OFS=","`

Comment: It's a little bit complicated for a newbie like me. But thanks anyway, now I know something additional.

Comment: @NZeeem Added some comments to it for your understanding